# How to get the job name on a groovy dynamic parameter?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I need get the name job in this example, I have a code for get the previous value of the build parameter with that code

```
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("nameOfJob").lastBuild.getBuildVariables().get("NameOfParameter");
```

The name of job now is hard coded, I need get this name will be the name of the current job. How can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Groovy Dynamic parameters do not have access to the usual environment variables that the rest of the jenkins job is privy to.

Here is a working hack to get the job name:

```
def build = Thread.currentThread().toString()
def regexp= ".+?/job/([^/]+)/.*"
def match = build  =~ regexp
def jobName = match[0][1]
```

Comment: For me this regexp worked recently: `def regexp= "executing ([^ ]+) .*"`

Answer (score 7):

Following works for me from the uno-choice plugin parameter Groovy script (means before the build is bound):

```
def job = this.binding.jenkinsProject
```

If you're interested in the job name, then:

```
def jobName = this.binding.jenkinsProject.name
```

Comment: just call `jenkinsProject`?

Comment: what is `jenkinsProject`

Comment: In "Execute system groovy script" this worked for me ```import hudson.model.*``` and ```this.binding.build.project.name```

Comment: `groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: binding for class: WorkflowScript` - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

If you are running a step in a project then there is an environment variable JOB_NAME

which in groovy you can access

```
String jobName = System.getenv('JOB_NAME')
```

If you want it post build then check this answer [How to get specific information about the current build project in Jenkins with Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121237/how-to-get-specific-information-about-the-current-build-project-in-jenkins-with)

As per the additional question, to get access to the Jenkins Job name  at the setup stage you need to use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) which supports groovy - it needs to return a map

```
println "currentJob -->${currentJob}"
println "currentBuild --> ${currentBuild}"

[currentJob: currentJob, currentBuild: currentBuild]
```

This is the output when I use a shell job to echo the new environment

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Evaluation the following Groovy script content: 

println "currentJob -->${currentJob}"
println "currentBuild --> ${currentBuild}"

[currentJob: currentJob, currentBuild: currentBuild]

currentJob -->hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@5ffe31a7[_xxx]
currentBuild --> _xxx #6
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_xxx
[_xxx] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3812821436584477615.sh
+ echo _xxx #6
_xxx #6 
+ echo hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@5ffe31a7[_xxx]
hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@5ffe31a7[_xxx]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You need to do some string manipulation to separate the job and build

Comment: You're right. if you do this in the dynamic property `System.getenv().each{println it} ` then it doesn't list the JENKINS environment.

Comment: Added example using EnvInject

Comment: Man thanks, but I don't know where code this.. `println "currentJob -->${currentJob}"
println "currentBuild --> ${currentBuild}"

[currentJob: currentJob, currentBuild: currentBuild]`

Answer (score 1):

```
(Thread.currentThread().toString() =~ /job\/(.*?)\//)[0][1]
```

Comment: I see the string looks like ```Thread[Executor #0 for master : executing jobname #11,5,main]```, so try this: ```def myJobName = (Thread.currentThread().toString() =~ /executing (\S*)/)[0][1]```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly be sure you use "Execute system Groovy script" step (*not* "Execute Groovy script").

The simplest answer for getting the job name is:

```
String JOB_NAME = build.project.name;
```

And just use `JOB_NAME` like you would in a shell script.

But since you actually need a job instance then use:

```
build.project.lastBuild.getBuildVariables().get("NameOfParameter");
```

BUT, to get parameters for current build (actually running at the moment) simply use:

```
// string
// (bool is also a string -- "true"/"false" string)
def someStr = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("someBuildParam");
// mapping to int
def someInt = build.buildVariableResolver.resolve("someBuildParam") as int;
```

Class names in Jenkins documentation are a bit tricky, so here are some tips:

- Any job is an [AbstractProject](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html).
- Any build is an [AbstractBuild](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html).

Answer (score 1):

this works for me within a script pipeline's script block

```
${env.getEnvironment().get('JOB_NAME')}
```

Answer (score 0):

`def jobName = env.JOB_NAME` works fine for me on 2.176 Enterprise rolling.
This has the added benefit of being whitelisted so you can use it a locked down Jenkins.