# Display Name of the current opened job in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: parameters, build, jenkins, hudson

The code below displays a list of all jobs in hudson:

```
 def projectlist = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
 projectlist.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each
 {
     job ->println(job.displayName)
 }
```

How can I get the name of the current job only?

Comment: What do you mean by the opened job ?

Comment: i mean the current job, to use it as a parameter

Comment: You say in the parameters or in a Step Build?

Comment: This script only lists jobs in the top level. That is to say, it does not recurse down into folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the next code you can get the Job Name in a Execute system Groovy script

```
this.binding.build.project.name
```

Comment: it works! , but still i am trying to get the value in a Dynamic Parameter with no luck

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in groovy code within a groovy build step - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin

```
String jobName = System.getenv('JOB_NAME')
```

But it will also be available directly in any step in the job

e.g. shell

```
 echo "$JOB_NAME"
```

Taken from here [How to get the job name on a groovy dynamic parameter in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600715/how-to-get-the-job-name-on-a-groovy-dynamic-parameter-in-jenkins/18601190#18601190)

Comment: agreed.  returns null

Comment: In a "Execute system Groovy script" task I see System.getenv('JOB_NAME') returns null. ```this.binding.build.project.name``` works (after ```import hudson.model.*```). Depending on where the groovy is called from (which plugin) you will see a different level of API parameters set or exposed so I'm guessing for ```System.getenv('JOB_NAME')``` YMMV depends on how early in job it is called and from what plugin it is called (as well as other things such as jenkins version, solar flare activity, . . . )

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Groovy script within ["Env Inject"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), you can get current build and current job by:

```
currentJob.getName()
currentBuild.toString()
```