# How can I get the seed job's name inside a Jenksin Job DSL script?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm using a Freestyle project / job with a `Process Job DSLs` build step as provided by the [Jenkins Job DSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin), i.e. that is the "seed" job. How can I, from within the code provided by `Use the provided DSL script`, get the seed job's name?

I've tried to apply the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600715/how-to-get-the-job-name-on-a-groovy-dynamic-parameter-in-jenkins) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All build variables are injected into the DSL scripts, see [Access the Jenkins Environment Variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#access-the-jenkins-environment-variables). The `JOB_NAME` variable contains the name of the seed job.

```
println JOB_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need to access the executor / build for that? The name  is statically defined in the job / project configuration, so I should be able to access it from there, or?